# Beautiful Soup and Selenium cannot scrape website contents

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape the contents of a webpage. Initially I tried to use BeautifulSoup, however I was unable to grab the contents because the contents are loaded in dynamically.

After reading around I tried to use Selenium based on people suggestions, however after doing so I'm still unable to grab the contents. The scraped contents is the same as Beautiful soup.

Is it just not possible to scrape the contents of this webpage? (ex: https://odb.org/TW/2021/08/11/accessible-to-all)

```
import datetime as d
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# BeautifulSoup Implementation
def devo_scrap():
    full_date = d.date.today()
    string_date = str(full_date)
    format_date = string_date[0:4] + '/' + string_date[5:7] + '/' + string_date[8:]
    url = "https://odb.org/" + format_date
    r = requests.get(url)
    
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

    return soup

print(devo_scrap())
```

So the above is Beautiful soup implementation. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is it just not possible to scrape? Thanks in advance.

(Updated with Selenium Implementation)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime as d

PATH = '' <chrome driver path>
driver = webdriver.Chrom(PATH)

full_date = d.date.today()
string_date = str(full_date)
format_date = string_date[0:4] + '/' + string_date[5:7] + '/' + string_date[8:]
url = "https://odb.org/" + format_date

content = driver.get(url)
print(content)
```

The content (html) grabbed with selenium is the same as with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: There is no way to scrape dynamic content by Soup.I saw the webpage,suggest you scrape it with selenium and wait a minute in code to let the page load

Comment: there is a typo error devo_scrap(). and you code works fine

Comment: Please try to mention your problem in above code! There is a typo so, we believe that's the only problem you have in the code.

Comment: there is no issues with the code. my issue is how best to scrape the above webpage. I tried using soup and wasn't able to grab the contents. selenium had the same results.

Comment: @EthanWu Should I provide minimal code in selenium? Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: one sec. I will will update with my selenium implementation and get your feedback. thank you

Comment: Ok I updated the description with selenium code

Comment: @EthanWu I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68736150/12446721) is what you want. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do :

```py
source = driver.page_source
```

to get the page source using selenium. And convert that `source` into `BeautifulSoup` as usual :

```py
source = BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")
```

Complete code with some improvement :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

now = datetime.today()
format_date= now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

driver = webdriver.<>(executable_path=r'<>')

url = "https://odb.org/" + format_date
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)
# To load page completely. 

content=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

print(content)

# Title :
print(content.find("h1",class_="devo-title").text)

# Content :
print(content.find("article",class_="content").text)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Letting the page load completely was the key :)

Comment: I encountered the same situation. webdriver works, but it has to open each page. For scraping a large amount of websites, it takes a long time. Are there faster ways?

Comment: @Alex, have you tried using ‘headless’ mode webdriver? It’s usually faster than non-headless ones. Also, in BeautifulSoup, the ‘lxml’ parser is pretty fast most of the time. You might want to check out other parsers as well. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737520) & those duplicate questions as well.

Comment: @imxitiz I tried to use `headless`. But it seems it won't scrape the details of the `HTML`.  For example https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.246.4935.1254

Answer (score 0):

Data comes from an API call which returns a list with a single dictionary. Some of the values in the dictionary are html so will need an html parser to parse out the info. You might choose to do this based on the associated keys. For now, for demo'ing contents, I have used a simple test of the whether value is a string and starts with "<". You should consider whether something more robust is required.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.experience.odb.org/devotionals/v2?site_id=1&status=publish&country=TW&on=08-11-2021', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = r.json()[0]

for k,v in data.items():
    print(k + ' :')
    if isinstance(v, str):
        if v.startswith('<'):
            soup = bs(v)
            print(soup.get_text(' '))
        else:
            print(v)
    else:
        print(v)
    print()
```